# Difference between knowledge base and database

Tags: database, prolog, nlp, storage

I know how data are stored and represented in a database but can't found any relevant information on how data(knowledge) is represented in a knowledge base.One answer would be they are stored in the form of facts and rules.But what about prolog where we store facts and rule and name them as a prolog database are they actually knowledge base and we simply call them as a database.So is it the case that both the term are used interchangably or there exist major differences between them.

Comment: It's a fuzzy term. The Wikipedia entry is reasonable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The differences between databases and knowledge bases are diminishing. Traditionally they have been the following:

Databases offer various properties that make them fit for transactional processing. Prolog does not offer those.

On the other hand the Prolog database and knowledge bases in general permit to store general terms/data while (traditional) databases required flat data. 
Prolog can also store general rules that contain variables.